# Setting border radius for Dash Bootstrap Components's CardGroup component or its parent Div doesn't work the same as for individual cards

Tags: python, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm building an app in Dash using the dbc module and all of my other components and UI elements have corners rounded for 20px. However, I use a CardGroup component to display some information as individual cards stitched together and it doesn't respond to CSS border-radius or Bootstrap's "rounded". A function returns the card group to a parent Div via a callback. I tried changing the parent Div style without success.

Only way to make this work is to set each card's border-radius manually, but since I'm using a for-loop to generate the cards, I can't assign different radius to first and last card respectively. Is there any way to style the CardGroup component to give rounded corners?

```
def generate_weather_card(weather_data):
    temp_feels_like = f'{round(weather_data["main"]["feels_like"] - 273.15, 1)} °C'
    temp_actual = f'{round(weather_data["main"]["temp"] - 273.15, 1)} °C'
    windspeed = f'{round(weather_data["wind"]["speed"]*3.6, 1)} km/h'

    if "gust" in weather_data["wind"].keys():
        windgust = f'{round(weather_data["wind"]["gust"]*3.6, 1)} km/h'
    else:
        windgust = "N/A"
    pressure = f'{weather_data["main"]["pressure"]} hPa'
    humidity = f'{weather_data["main"]["humidity"]} %'

    contents = {
        "Temperature": [(temp_feels_like, "Feels like"),
                        (temp_actual, "Actual")],
        "Wind": [(windspeed, "Wind speed"), (windgust, "Wind gusts")],
        "Atmosphere": [(pressure, "Pressure"), (humidity, "Humidity")]
    }
    card_style = {"width": "6cm", "height": "7cm", "text-align": "center"}

    cards = []

    for key in contents.keys():
        card = dbc.Card([
            dbc.CardHeader(key, className="fw-bold fs-3"),
            dbc.CardBody([
                html.H2(contents[key][0][0],
                        className="card-text fw-bolder text-secondary"),
                html.P(contents[key][0][1],
                       className="card-text fw-bold fs-5"),
                html.H2(contents[key][1][0],
                        className="card-text fw-bolder text-secondary"),
                html.P(contents[key][1][1], className="card-text fw-bold fs-5")
            ],
                         style={"font-size": "18px"})
        ],
                        class_name="align-self-center",
                        style=card_style)
        cards.append(card)

    return dbc.CardGroup(cards, style={"border-radius":"20px"})
```

^^ Last line doesn't round the corners. I also tried changing the "tag" property of CardGroup to "img", which didn't help at all.

```
dbc.Col([
                    html.Div("Select location to display weather data",
                             id="weather_main",
                             className="ms-4 me-4 mb-4 mt-2")
                ],
                        width={"size": 7})
```

^^ The column and parent Div where the CardGroup goes from this callback

```
@app.callback([
    Output("weather_main", "children"),
    Output("wicon", "children"),
    Output("situation", "children")
], [State("map", "center"),
    Input("location_name", "children")],
              prevent_initial_call=True)
def parse_weather_icon(lat_lon, lname):
    weather_data = get_weather(lat_lon)
    return [
        generate_weather_card(weather_data),
        html.Img(
            src=
            f'http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{weather_data["weather"][0]["icon"]}@2x.png',
            style={"height": "2cm"}),
        weather_data["weather"][0]["description"].capitalize()
    ]
```

Any ideas on why it doesn't work?
Thanks

App layout with above code:
[App layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0stu.jpg)